# How can I know the GUEST Windows IP under HOST Ubuntu?

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, virtualbox

I want the internet connection to the Virtual GUEST Windows when Ubuntu is the HOST, under Virtualbox. I use NAT but the only IPs are for port-forwardings. ipconfig under Windows returns /dev/null, meaning no connection-thing set up  so I need to somehow set it up in Virtual Box -settings but I cannot understand them. Could someone explain how to do that in Virtual Box?

It is done somehow by clicking the menus but I am a bit lost here.

Answer (score 1):

You should consider switching to bridge mode, this way your HOST will not have to run a DHCP server, and you won't have to forward ports or such. Really, it's the easiest thing to do. When it is in bridge mod the VM will request an IP from the same server your HOST does.